# Event when ComboBoxItem in ComboBox gets selected

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

What event do I have to listen for, to get notified when a user selects an option from a (editable) [WPF ComboBox control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.combobox_members%28VS.90%29.aspx)?

Do I have to access the Items property first to then listen to `Items.CurrentChanged`? And if so, how do I add that listener in XAML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about the SelectionChanged event?

EDIT: Added a simple example

```
<ComboBox SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

and in code-behind:

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: Ahh, how could I not see that.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

if you are looking to do it in MVVM then its:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem={Binding Path=SelectedItem}/>
```

assuming you have a SelectedItem property in your ViewModel set to the proper objectType.